# Threshold values for viola jones object detection

Tags: face-detection, object-detection, adaboost, viola-jones

I am trying to perform Adaboost training stated by Viola and Jones in their paper on rapid object detection. However, I do not understand how to get the threshold values that will classify the faces from non faces for each of the 160k features. Is this a threshold you set manually? or is this based on some kind of maths ?

Can someone please explain the maths to me thanks a lot.

Comment: Which one of the thresholds you do not understand how it is obtained? The strong classifier threshold or the weak classifier threshold?

Comment: I do not understand how the thresholds are obtained for the selection of weak classifiers which will help classify the images from the non face images with the lowest error. As for the strong classifier I understand that it has to be greater that 0.5*sum_of_alphasOfWeakClassifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the best way to describe what happens during threshold assignment of the weak classifiers in every boosting round is a ROC analysis of the weak classifier performance. A great introduction on ROC analysis [was written by Tom Fawcett](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patrec.2005.10.010). The full algorithm that does what you want is described in [Shappire and Freund`s book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262017180), section 3.4.2.