# Viola jones weak classifier explanation

Tags: face-detection, viola-jones, haar-classifier

I have been trying to understand the paper by viola n jones on face detection. I am not totally sure what this equation's parameters mean from section 3

```
h(x, f, p, theta) = 1 ; if pf(x) < p theta
```

What I understood was feature (`f`) is the value that is obtained by running any of those 5 basic features explained in the beginning of the paper over integral image of `x`.

What I can't understand properly is the threshold 'theta' and polarity 'p'. Does this `p`mean positive image and negative image and can have value of +1 or -1? And how do I calculate theta. This equation is vital to boosting section so I can't go further. Please help if I am making myself clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

You must understand that the weak classifier `h` uses a Haar-like feature `f` to classify an image subwindow `x`. The parameter `p`, if equal to `-1`, simply causes the inversion of the comparison sign of the condition `if pf(x) < p theta`.

The parameter `theta` is simply a threshold. Say, for instance, that `p = +1`. If `f(x) < theta`, then `h(x, f, p, theta) = +1`, i.e., the weak classifier considers `x` a face.

Comment: Thank you. Does this `p` get inverted somewhere in code flow or is it user selectable ? Please don't mind if this seems a retarded question.
And how do I get `theta`?

Comment: In the 'classical' approach to do this, both `p` and `theta` are set at the same time, for every Haar wavelet, in every Adaboost iteration. I posted some useful references in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051796/threshold-values-for-viola-jones-object-detection).